# AWS SAM template error : collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'startswith

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sam

I am getting this error while using SAM template for deploying resources

below is the script
- sam package --template-file test.json --s3-bucket $s3_bucket --s3-prefix packages/my_folder/ --output-template-file samtemplate.yml

getting this error even tried after rollbacking to previous working status

return any([url.startswith(prefix) for prefix in ["s3://", "http://", "https://"]])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/providers/sam_stack_provider.py", line 250, in 
return any([url.startswith(prefix) for prefix in ["s3://", "http://", "https://"]])
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'startswith'

After adding some debug message I got this error
2021-04-22 06:42:32,820 | Unable to resolve property S3bucketname: OrderedDict([('Fn::Select', ['0', OrderedDict([('Fn::Split', ['/', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'TemplateS3BucketName')])])])])]). Leaving as is.

Comment: We can't see your template. At a guess, are there any places in your template where a URL string is required but you've provided a dictionary (an object within braces)?

Comment: Yes we have this dynamic substitution everywhere in the script where we are using braces instead of direct url

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of this template to your post?

Comment: @jarmod After adding debug command in the script I am getting this error 2021-04-22 06:42:32,820 | Unable to resolve property S3bucketname: OrderedDict([('Fn::Select', ['0', OrderedDict([('Fn::Split', ['/', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'TemplateS3BucketName')])])])])]). Leaving as is.